# How to hide 'Take Photo' menu item when using xamarin plugin "ImageCropper.Forms"

Tags: ios, image, xamarin.forms, ngx-image-cropper

I'm using xamarin forms to build an app and within this app I used plugin:
ImageCropper.Forms.Fix.v2
For some reason the function of 'Take Photo' of this plugin in my iOS app doesn't work (has added access right in the plist, it just return image is null exception, and Xam.Plugin.Media version is the latest 5.0.1)
But actually, my app doesn't want this 'Take Photo' shows to the end user,
Any want to know how to hide this 'Take Photo' menu easily?
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smUKO.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the plugin is open source - you can modify it to exclude the Take Photo menu if you need to

Comment: Thanks Json, after modified his source code, then I have successfully removed the 'Take Photo' item.